# Css submenu not remain visible after menu unhover no javascript

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I want to use only css, no javascript. When I mouse hover the top-level menu I can display the submenu, but as soon as I unhover the top-level menu the submenu disapper. How could I solve this without using javascript? Have I missed something?

I tried to use `.has-children:hover + .sub-menu {display: block;}` to display the submenu when I mouse hover the top-level menu, but I have no idea what I can code to keep visible the submenu.

The HTML code is:

```css
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.header li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.header li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.menu {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
}
.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.open-menu-link {
  display: none;
}
.has-children:hover + .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="has-children" href="#about">Haschildren</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="has-children" href="#careers">About</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#link1">Child 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Child 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">end</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you `has-children` class onto the `li` and then make your selector:

```
.has-children:hover > .sub-menu
```

**Updated snippet:**

```css
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.header li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.header li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.menu {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
}
.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.open-menu-link {
  display: none;
}
.has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <header class="header">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#about">Haschildren</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#careers">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#link1">Child 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link2">Child 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">end</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `has-children` to the li and use the li's hover event to display the submenu.

```css
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.header li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.header li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
.menu {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  max-height: none;
}
.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.open-menu-link {
  display: none;
}
.has-children:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children"><a href="#about">Haschildren</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#link1">Child 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#link2">Child 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#link3">Child 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children"><a href="#careers">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#link1">Child 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#link2">Child 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">end</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```